# Custom control problem with memory usage and navigation

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

[image: Custom list style control]

Above is an image for a custom control that I'm working on. It's actually three separate controls in a windows form. It's a container control which holds multiple instances of a "Platform/console" control. The "Platform" control holds multiple instances of a "Game" control. The consoles are collapsible which will hide the games in the list.

Now the problem I'm having is the fact that when a person has say 3000 game titles, the memory usage is up around 500MB, and the control is very sluggish. Now I haven't optimized the creation out of the application thread yet, but even after creation it's a pig.

How would a person go about freeing resources on controls that have moved off screen? Is there a quicker way than testing each control to see if it's in some visible area? Is there a different way I should be designing this control?

I don't have extensive knowledge in C# so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is an awesome set of PS1 games you have there :D

Comment: lol. Yep I'm a FF fan :)

Comment: These kind of questions are never fun to answer, you've done a considerable amount of work already and *really* solving the problem you've been ignoring for a while means throwing out a *lot* of code.  Controls are *very* expensive and you've got way too many of them.  You avoid using a control with OnDrawItem and OnMouseDown/Up.

Comment: My lack of knowledge with controls really shows. I had no idea the cost of each one.

Comment: @Hans Are you suggesting that I should be overriding the drawitem event of my custom control, or creating an OnDrawItem even and hooking it in the parent application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your Control "Virtualized" you might reduce the memory footprint. Have a look at ListView, if you set ownerDrawn = true and VirtualMode =true and VirtualListSize =3000 the following code will create items (and store them) and do custom drawing.

You might be in for some extra programming because on your owner drawn control nothing comes for free...

```
// should be a cache of some sort, WeakReference'd etc, this is NOT reducing memory load (it is adding memory load)
        Dictionary<Int32, ListViewItem> dict = new Dictionary<int, ListViewItem>();

        private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
        {

            ListViewItem lvi = null;
            if (dict.ContainsKey(e.ItemIndex))
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("from cache:{0}", e.ItemIndex));
                lvi = dict[e.ItemIndex];
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("created:{0}", e.ItemIndex));
                lvi = new ListViewItem { Text = String.Format("item:{0}", e.ItemIndex) };
                lvi.SubItems.Add( new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem{Text = String.Format("si:{0}", e.ItemIndex)});
                dict.Add(e.ItemIndex, lvi);
            }
            e.Item = lvi; 
        }

        private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            // you can draw yourself...
            // e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 0f, 0f);
            e.DrawText();
        }
```

Comment: I had hoped for a wider variety of answers. Thanks rene for your contribution. I'm going to have to abandon the control for now and use something more traditional.